# saving cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hey I am trying to save **cookie** and then load/read it again on reload. But whenever I reload I get error message `myCookie is undefined`. Can Someone help me out.

```
var myCookie

window.onload = function () {

  console.log(myCookie);
  var a = document.getElementById("style1");
  if (myCookie == undefined) {
    console.log("new");
  var myCookie = document.cookie = "common.css";  
  } else {
    console.log("old");
  }
   a.href = myCookie;
}

function change()
{

    var a = document.getElementById("style1");
    if(myCookie=="common.css")
    {
      myCookie  = document.cookie = "common2.css";
    }else{
      myCookie  = document.cookie = "common.css";
    }
    a.href = myCookie;
}
```

Comment: Because, whenever the page load myCookie set as undefined variable. So You will try the local storage.

Comment: @MathsRkBala - since he's asking about a cookie, the solution is to start by checking for the cookie 1st and forget about the variable altogether. he is also declaring myCookie again.

Comment: look at how to set cookies.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Working with cookies is a pain.  It is very easy to overwrite what might be important cookie data.  I strongly encourage you to find a library where someone has done the heavy lifting for you such as js-cookie (formerly jquery-cookie) https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.

Comment: Thanks everyone. all very useful.

Comment: Turns out my code did work. Just not on Chrome apparently (the webpage was stored on my local system)

Comment: @RetroPanda - your code does not work. `myCookie` will always be `undefined` on `window.onload`. as I wrote below, you need to initialise it with document.cookie 1st

Comment: @Ted yes sorry. There were minor errors but after i fixed those thanks to you guys. It did work BUT not in chrome. would be awesome if you could tell me why that is or how to correct it

Comment: use a library. js cookies are a pain to work with using only native code. I recommend https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie. you can easily set cookies: `Cookies.set('name', 'value');` and get cookies: `Cookies.get('name');`

Answer (score 1):

you need to read more about JavaScript cookies. you are using an unnecessary variable which you're declaring again on local scope.

when window loads an uninitialised variable such as

```
var myCookie;
```

will always be `undefined`. so you should start by initialling with the `document.cookie`

```
var myCookie = document.cookie;
```

now, to set the cookie for later use, you will need a key like:

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=myValue";
```

you can read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @JonSG - are you asking me ? :)

Comment: Someone gave you a downvote and I thought your answer did not warrant it.  I was hoping they would explain why.  The downvote has been removed though so I guess all is good again :-)  Going to delete my comment about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont especify a expire date by default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed.

```
document.cookie = "style=common.css; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2016 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

then you could read with:

```
function read_cookie(key)
{
    var result;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? (result[1]) : null;
}
read_cookie('style'); //common.css
```

My suggestion is to use something different than Cookies. Perhaps a polyfill for LocalStorage it would be better.